# How do I have one Userform event procedure (checkbox click) control multiple IF THEN statements?

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

Hey so I am a beginner with VBA but here is my dilemma:

Creating an excel userform with VBA -

I have a combobox with the numbers 1-8, the number of textboxes shown for the user to fill out is based off of the number selected in the combobox.

I also have a checkbox which, when "TRUE", enables the user to create a custom title for the output of the textbox.

---

Ex: 
Number of Goals = **2**
*Custom Label Goals? [x] (True*)

**Goal 1** : $1,000,000
 *"New Home"*

**Goal 2** : $50,000
"Boat"

---

My issue is that I cannot get the number of custom label boxes to be the same as the number of goals selected. So when Number of goals is 2, 8 custom goal textboxes still show up if the checkbox is TRUE.

I found a way using the code below, but when I enter the second IF THEN statement, the first no longer responds to the clicking the checkbox:

```
Private Sub cbIMPLBL_Click()

If cboIMP.Value = "1" And cbIMPLBL.Value = "True" Then
   txtIMPLBL1.Visible = True
   txtIMPLBL2.Visible = False
   txtIMPLBL3.Visible = False
   txtIMPLBL4.Visible = False
   txtIMPLBL5.Visible = False
   txtIMPLBL6.Visible = False
   txtIMPLBL7.Visible = False
   txtIMPLBL8.Visible = False
Else
   txtIMPLBL1.Visible = False
   txtIMPLBL2.Visible = False
   txtIMPLBL3.Visible = False
   txtIMPLBL4.Visible = False
   txtIMPLBL5.Visible = False
   txtIMPLBL6.Visible = False
   txtIMPLBL7.Visible = False
   txtIMPLBL8.Visible = False
End If

If cboIMP.Value = "2" And cbIMPLBL.Value = "True" Then
   txtIMPLBL1.Visible = True
   txtIMPLBL2.Visible = True
   txtIMPLBL3.Visible = False
   txtIMPLBL4.Visible = False
   txtIMPLBL5.Visible = False
   txtIMPLBL6.Visible = False
   txtIMPLBL7.Visible = False
   txtIMPLBL8.Visible = False
Else
   txtIMPLBL1.Visible = False
   txtIMPLBL2.Visible = False
   txtIMPLBL3.Visible = False
   txtIMPLBL4.Visible = False
   txtIMPLBL5.Visible = False
   txtIMPLBL6.Visible = False
   txtIMPLBL7.Visible = False
   txtIMPLBL8.Visible = False
End If

End Sub
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated. 
As I am just beginning is there a different way I am supposed to be doing this, e.g. not writing all of this out individually, but as a control or function (not sure what the term would be) of some sort?

Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Look into select case statements.

Comment: Thank you @Scott Craner , what might that look like in controlling visibility?

Comment: Scott gave you information on what to investigate. Have you tried a Google search for `VBA select case` as he suggested?

Comment: @Ken White Yes I did and it is definitely helpful, just could not figure how to create a Select Case statement that selects based off of two Cases. I am going to review Scott's post below now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently both if statements will fire.  So if cboIMP.Value = "1" then it first runs through the first if statement and unhides the first text box. But it immediately runs the second if statement and because it does not = "2" it re hides the text box.

There are two choices a select case statement or else if statements.

Select Case:

```
If cbIMPLBL.Value = "True" Then
    Select Case cboIMP.Value
        Case 1
            'hide/unhide for 1
        Case 2
            'hide/unhide for 2
        Case Else
            'Hide all
    End Select
End If
```

Else if

```
If cbIMPLBL.Value = "True" Then
    if cboIMP.Value = 1 then
       'do your stuff
    Else if cboIMP.Value = 2 then
       'do your stuff
    Else
       'hide everything
    end if
End If
```

This way once the code finds a true it ignores all others.  If it does not find any true statements it runs the else.

Comment: @Ken White and Scott, I just started using VBA on Monday and have just relied on google till this first post Have any recommendations on resources/books to help me get a comprehensive understanding of VBA? Appreciate any feedback.

Comment: @redcase That is a loaded question.  It is very personal, based on how one learns.  Most of my info came from google and trial and error, with a few books thrown in.  there is no one way that works for everyone.